# List out of bound in below code

Tags: controller, exception, list, upload, loop

I am getting list out of bound error here in below code. Can someone please help me?

Apex class snippet:

```
for(Incident_abv__c  inc : [select Name,Id from Incident_abv__c where name=:csvRecordData[j]]) // this line errors out
           {if(inc.name == csvRecordData[j])            
           {inc.status_abv__c = 'Open';
           inc.Report_Publish_Date_abv__c = Date.today();
            if(inc.Rep_abv__c !=null)
                inc.OwnerId = inc.Rep_abv__c; 
           }                                                                             
           sObjectList.add(inc);
           system.debug('saikat'+inc.name) ;
          // break;
           }
```

APEX CLASS CODE:

```
Public with sharing class csvFileReaderController {
public Blob csvFileBody{get;set;}
Public string csvAsString{get;set;}
Public String[] csvfilelines{get;set;}
Public String[] inputvalues{get;set;}
Public List<string> fieldList{get;set;}
Public List<Incident_abv__c> sObjectList{
    get{
        if(sObjectList == null) sObjectList = new List<Incident_abv__c>();
        return sObjectList;
    }
    set;
}
  public csvFileReaderController(){
    csvfilelines = new String[]{};
    fieldList = New List<string>();
    //sObjectList = New List<sObject>();
  }

    Public void readcsvFile(){
   csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
   csvfilelines = csvAsString.split('\n');
   system.debug('saikat'+'@'+csvfilelines);
   inputvalues = new String[]{};
   for(string st:csvfilelines[0].split(','))
       fieldList.add(st);  

   for(Integer i=1;i<csvfilelines.size();i++){
       //Incident_abv__c inc= new Incident_abv__c() ;
       string[] csvRecordData = csvfilelines[i].split(',');
       system.debug('saikat'+'@'+csvRecordData[0] );
     for(Integer j=0;j<csvfilelines.size()-1;j++)  {
     //public List<Incident_abv__c > inc{get;set;} 
     if(String.isNotEmpty(csvRecordData[j]) || String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[j]) )
     {for(Incident_abv__c  inc : [select Name,Id from Incident_abv__c where name=:csvRecordData[j]])
       {if(inc.name == csvRecordData[j])            
       {inc.status_abv__c = 'Open';
       inc.Report_Publish_Date_abv__c = Date.today();
        if(inc.Rep_abv__c !=null)
            inc.OwnerId = inc.Rep_abv__c; 
       }   
       //if(!sObjectList.contains(inc))                                                                          
       sObjectList.add(inc);
       system.debug('saikat'+inc.name) ;
      // break;
       } 
       }
     }
       //system.debug('saikat'+inc.name) ;
       update sObjectlist;
       sObjectlist.clear();

   }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a value at position **j** in the csvRecordData array? You should check before executing the SOQL query

```
if(String.isNotEmpty(csvRecordData[j]) || String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[j]) ){
    //Your for loop here
}
```

Make sure you have the right brackets closed at the correct time. See if your code below performs the same way as your code

```
   for(Integer i=1;i<csvfilelines.size();i++){
       //Incident_abv__c inc= new Incident_abv__c() ;
       string[] csvRecordData = csvfilelines[i].split(',');
       system.debug('saikat'+'@'+csvRecordData[0] );
       for(Integer j=0;j<csvfilelines.size()-1;j++)  {
           //public List<Incident_abv__c > inc{get;set;} 
           if(String.isNotEmpty(csvRecordData[j]) || String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[j]) ){
               for(Incident_abv__c  inc : [select Name,Id from Incident_abv__c where name=:csvRecordData[j]]){
                    if(inc.name == csvRecordData[j]){
                       inc.status_abv__c = 'Open';
                       inc.Report_Publish_Date_abv__c = Date.today();
                       if(inc.Rep_abv__c !=null){
                          inc.OwnerId = inc.Rep_abv__c;
                       }
                    }   
               }
               sObjectList.add(inc);            
               system.debug('saikat'+inc.name);
               // break;
           } 
       }
   }
```

Comment: This works for one record but fails for multiples. I am putting here my whole class. Please have a look.

Comment: You should open the curly bracket before the if and close it after just like in my answer. The if statement should work multiple times as it will be in the for loop with the j counter

Comment: I have editted that still getting same error

Comment: What type of error do you get?

Comment: Please find it here::    System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 1
Error is in expression '{!readcsvFile}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page csvfilereadercontroller: Class.csvFileReaderController.readcsvFile: line 37, column 1

Comment: Updated my answer